# Can't read Firebase database, data returns null

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to get a specific user from the database but I can't, also I would like to check if there is already a node with the same name (uid). I don't want to get the whole list of users and then retrieve one from it because I don't think that's good for perfomance, my idea is to directly get the user from the database

I tried many ways but everything I try returns null, I can't get the values from dataSnapshot. I use an interface to make sure I execute the code after the reading is done

```
        currentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        mUserReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users/"+currentUser.getUid());
        mUserReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);

                dataStatus.dataIsLoaded(user);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
```

Here the interface

```
    public interface DataStatus{
        void dataIsLoaded(User user);
    }
```

And when I try to get the user it shows NullPointerException

```
            UserUtils userUtils = new UserUtils();

            userUtils.getUser(new UserUtils.DataStatus() {
                @Override
                public void dataIsLoaded(User user) {
                    mUser = user;
                }
            });
```

User creation, when I call this method I do `uid = currentUser.getUid()`

```
    public void createNewUser(String uid, String name, String email, DataStatus dataStatus) {
        mUserReference = mDatabase.child("users").child(uid);
        mUserReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                user = new User(name, email);
                mDatabase.child("users").child(uid).setValue(user);
                dataStatus.dataIsLoaded(user);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
```

Here the rules

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[Here's how my data base is organized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wub5F.png)

**SOLVED**
The problem was a piece of code, which I didn't include here, that was trying to get access to the user outside the `dataIsLoaded` interface method, and as `onDataChange` is asynchronous the user hadn't been downloaded yet so it was conflicting with the code.

Comment: Can you show the code for user creation

Comment: Yes, I just added it

Comment: I mean user creation in firebase.

Comment: Can you put code for user creation in firebase.

Comment: Yes, sorry, now it's done

Comment: Good to hear you found the cause of your problems. Since that isn't related to the code you posted here, it won't be of use to future visitors, so I'm voting to close as off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO community

Please use `.child()` method instead of cascading nodes with "/" as below
Also check if the value of the datasnapshot is not null using `.exists()` method

```
currentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
mUserReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference.child("users").child(currentUser.getUid());
mUserReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if(dataSnapshot.exists()) {
            user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
            dataStatus.dataIsLoaded(user);
        }
    }
    // rest of code
```

Feel free if you need further support

**UPDATE**

Please replace your listener with below

```
currentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
mUserReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference.child("users").child(currentUser.getUid());

Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference.child("users").orderByKey() 
        .equalTo(currentUser.getUid()); 

query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot singleSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) { // dataSnapshot contains set of returned result of the query
            User user = singleSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
            if (user != null) {
                dataStatus.dataIsLoaded(user);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I already tried using `.child` instead but it doesn't work either

Comment: Can you log the "currentUser" id and make sure it's already in your database node "users" before adding listener?

Comment: I debbuged it to check and it is in the database, you can compare it with the image in the main post [currentUser uid](https://gyazo.com/6cba6daef7770a7db68bd6ac4de82d3b)

Comment: does onDataChange() is triggered with the right user? .. if yes does dataStatus.dataIsLoaded(user); correctly update the user field of userUtils object ?

Comment: I'm almost sure it is, the problem is that when I do `user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);` user still null so `dataStatus.dataIsLoaded(user)` update a null object. I think it doesn't even enter onDataChange() method

Comment: could you wrap code in onDatachange() within if (dataSnapshot.exists())

Comment: I doesn't work, I already tried it and I now did it again to check and nothing. I tried to do `Log.e` inside the `onDataChange()` and it didn't log anything I don't know if it's because it is asynchronous or what is happening

Comment: does it work with addChildEventListener() instead of addListenerForSingleValueEvent() ?

Comment: I just uploaded it, can it be that `dataSnapshot.getValue()` can only return the childs of the user (email, name, etc) and not the whole object?

Comment: I just updated the answer, plz tell me if still returns null

Comment: It keeps returning null, but if I add ChildEventListener() to `.child(currentUser.getUid())` I will be listening to the childs of the user and not the user itself

Comment: It returns null, I'm trying all I can imagine but it doesn't work

Comment: I found the solutions, I was my mistake, a pieace of code I didn't pay attention to, thank very much any way for helping me

Comment: glad you found it .. any time

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO community.

When did you call your function to read the user content?

it might be an asynchronous problem.

To make sure, make a function where the user is the parameter and call it once you read something from the DB (onDataChange).

Plus, did you try to print out what is inside " user " when you read it? if it gives you null, the problem is within the path for sure. If so, use .child("users").child(currentUser.getUid())

Comment: I call it from `OnViewCreated` of a map fragment, I tested it with a function and it is null